# After resetting transition, div stays visible; no new transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a `<div>` display and then fade out, on button click.

This works so long as the user waits for the fade to complete between `<button>` presses.

My problem is, if the `<button>` is clicked *while* the fade is ongoing, the `<div>` needs to immediately reappear, and then fade out.

I've managed to get it to immediately reappear, but now it doesn't fade out again.

*To get an easier idea of what I'm doing, take a look at **[the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CT8g9/)** I've setup.*

Can anyone help me get this to fade out if clicked whilst already fading out?

I'm only targeting [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit).

```
<div id="saved">Saved!</div>
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

```
function save()
{
    // Little "Saved!" div
    var div = document.getElementById('saved');

    // If still showing from previous save
    if(div.style.visibility === 'visible')
    {
        resetTransition();
        div.style.visibility = 'visible';
        //div.style.opacity = 0;
        console.log('reset');
    }

    // On transition end
    div.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', resetTransition);

    function resetTransition()
    {
        // Disable transitions
        div.className = 'notransition';

        // Hide the div and reset the opacity
        div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        div.style.opacity = 1;

        // Need time to let CSS changes (^) refresh
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            // Re-enable transitions
            div.className = '';

            // Remove the event listener by way of cloning
            var dolly = div.cloneNode(true);
            div.parentNode.replaceChild(dolly, div);
        }, 1);
    }

    // Show the div and fade out - on timer due to "if still showing" needing
    // to process first
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        div.style.visibility = 'visible';
        div.style.opacity = 0;
    }, 1);
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save);
```

```
div#saved
{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.25s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.75s;
    background-color: #FFC;
    /* Courtesy of http://fatcow.com/free-icons */
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/JMlclKE.png');
    background-position: 3px 4px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px 4px 10px 52px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 68px;
}

.notransition
{
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition-delay: none !important;
}

button
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CT8g9/2/), moving the cloning to the top and clearing the timeout.

```
// Little "Saved!" div
clearTimeout(save.t);
var dolly = document.getElementById('saved');
// Remove the event listener by way of cloning
var div = dolly.cloneNode(true);
dolly.parentNode.replaceChild(div, dolly);

/* etc til */
save.t = setTimeout(/* */);
```

Comment: You did most of the work. Sometimes just takes a second set of eyes.

Comment: Yeah a second set of eyes definitely helps! I also added a `if(typeof(save.t) !== 'undefined')` before the `clearTimeout(save.t)` to stop the first one throwing an exception. Thanks again!